# Comparison of strings in C

Tags: c, string

```
char str1[]="abc";
char str2[]="abc";

if (str1==str2)
    printf("Yes")
else
    printf("No");
```

I am refreshing my C.  Wouldn't the above code return "Yes"? I think it would because str1 and str2 are pointing to the first elements of the array, which are the same (the letter a).  Please advise if I am missing something.

Comment: No.  You are comparing addresses.  That is why strcmp exists.

Comment: really depends if the compiler does string interning as an optimisation

Comment: You need to find out what a pointer is.

Comment: You do compare the addresses instead of the value of the strings.

Comment: So, would *str1 and *str2 return "Yes"?

Comment: use strcmp like this : if(strcmp(str1,str2) == 0)

Answer (score 0):

The variable name of a char array is equivalent to a pointer to the address of the first element of the array.  Therefore, what you are comparing are pointers.  They are not equivalent because the address of the two variables in memory are not equivalent.

Comment: Got it.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are comparing string addresses. So without optimisations, the expected answer is "No" (two different strings, hence two addresses).

However, most modern compilers perform string interning (merging identical constants strings), in which case the answer would be "Yes". Note this only happens for string literals.

For instance, GCC 4.9.2 does this by default:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main()
{
    char *ptr1 = "abc";
    char *ptr2 = "abc";
    printf("%p\n%p\n",ptr1,ptr2);
    if (ptr1 == ptr2) printf("yes\n");
}

gcc -o /tmp/file /tmp/file.c

/tmp/file
0x400660
0x400660
yes
```

Interestingly, behaviour is different (i.e. no interning) when declaring the variables `char ptr1[]` and `char ptr2[]`. This is because, in that case, the compiler actually places the strings on the stack (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1704407/what-is-the-difference-between-char-s-and-char-s-in-c)).

As stated in comments, the proper way to compare strings is `strcmp` and related functions.

Comment: In *all* cases the answer would be "No" to the code posted in the question. You appear to be answering a different question...

Comment: yeah, admittedly, I was figuring it out as I went along :)